# envio de datos en una cadena

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

hola amigos estoy tratando de enviar un dato junto a los que vienen desde la base, pero no se como podría mandarlo solo es la variable Nbatida = 1, ese dato lo quiero mandar ya que cuando se lista por no llevarlo, los datos numéricos que están relacionados los manda a nulos, les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

```
var detalles = []; 
   function agregarDetalleB(id_Dproducto,materiales,estado){
    $.ajax({
        url:"../ajax/Dproducto.php?op=buscar_DproductoB",
        type:"POST",
        data:{id_Dproducto:id_Dproducto,materiales:materiales,estado:estado},
        dataType: 'json', // jQuery convertirá la respuesta en JSON
        async: true,         
        success:function(data){
           
            console.log(data);
            
            if(data.error != '') {
                alert(data.error);
            } else {
                
                listarDetallesB(data.datos);
                                
// junto a eso estos quisiera mandar el valor Nbatida = 1


            }
            $('#modalDproducto').modal("hide");
        }  
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de la función `listarDetallesB()` solo verifica que existe la propiedad, de lo contrario, asigna 1:

```
function listarDetallesB(detalles) {
    // Código original: definición de variables
    for(var i = 0; i < detalles.length; i++) {
        if( detalles[i].estado == 1 ) {
            if(typeof detalles[i].Nbatida == 'undefined' || !detalles[i].Nbatida) {
                // No está definida o tiene un valor "falsy" (cero, cadena vacía, etc.)
                detalles[i].Nbatida = 1;
            }
            // Código original: armas el HTML con los datos
        }
    }
    // Código original: aplicas los cambios necesarios al HTML
}
```

Comment: gracias amigo si manda el uno

Comment: disculpa amigo en la parte de listarDetallesB se agrega datos que cambian cuando se agrega Nbatida, pero recibia datos que la forma anterior que tenia. por obj que llegaba por un push pero ahora no los recibe de la misma manera y no logra a cambiar los datos

Comment: function setNbatida(event, obj, idx){
    event.preventDefault();
    detalles[idx].Nbatida = parseInt(obj.value);
    recalcular(idx);
  }

Comment: @wilbertpalacios, en tu pregunta anterior asignabas directamente el valor `Nbatida : 1`. Con esta respuesta, la ventaja es que si el dato ya existe no se va a modificar, si no existe, lo crea. En todo caso, deberías modificar la pregunta para agregar esa otra función y explicar cómo y cuándo la ejecutas.

Comment: ok amigo entiendo gracias